# How to eliminate duplicate and merge column value to single text in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to join three table and get the results, however, one of the tables has multiple event_code for the same CSO_Item_key which is resulting in duplicate records.
Please note my source is Vertica and Target is SQL server.
I tried stuff and for XML approach but is not working with vertica; it says incorrect syntax XML.
Is there any other solution

Table 1

```
Entry Date      Cso Item Key    Fail Code
8/1/2018 4:28   BLXB796201      CSL120
8/1/2018 4:40   BLXB799101      CLL250
8/1/2018 4:55   BLXB803001      CMS130
8/1/2018 5:08   BLXB806201      CNE100
```

Table 2

```
Cso Item Key    Event Code
BLXB796201      GTS
BLXB796201      LC28
BLXB796201      SDR4
BLXB799101      GTS
BLXB799101      LC28
BLXB799101      SDR4
BLXB803001      GTS
BLXB803001      LC28
BLXB803001      SDR4
BLXB806201      GTS
BLXB806201      LC28
BLXB806201      SDR4
```

Table 3

```
Fail Code  Desc
CSL120     Bad Part
CLL250     Unit Scrapped
CNE100     OS Reinstall
CBN101     NTF
```

Expected Result:

```
Entry_Date     Cso_Item_Key Fail_Code   Desc         Event_Code
8/1/2018 4:28   BLXB796201   CSL120   Bad Part       GTS,LC28,SDR4
8/1/2018 4:40   BLXB799101   CLL250   Unit Scrapped  GTS,LC28,SDR4
8/1/2018 4:55   BLXB803001   CMS130   Null           GTS,LC28,SDR4
8/1/2018 5:08   BLXB806201   CNE100   OS Reinstall   GTS,LC28,SDR4
```

Screenshot of data:

[image]

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2022/concat-aggregates-sql-server-clr-function/

Comment: I am using 2016

Answer (score 0):

One of the only solutions I've seen for this is the strings_package extension which can be found [here](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package) on github. With it, you can use the group_concat function like so:

```
-- get a list of nodes
select group_concat(node_name) over () from nodes;

-- nodes with storage for a projection
select schema_name,projection_name,
group_concat(node_name) over (partition by schema_name,projection_name) 
from (select distinct node_name,schema_name,projection_name from storage_containers) sc order by schema_name, projection_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trying to do it all in SQL - a bit cheating as I am relying on the fact that Table_2 always has 3 different event codes for each CSO Item Key.

If that is not the case, you would have to add a few rows - up to the maximum number of Event Codes per CSO Item Key, to the `i` index table I'm creating as a Common Table expression, and you would have to LEFT JOIN that `i` table to `tb2`, and add some NULL processing logic to the expression, for example: `||','||MAX(CASE i.i WHEN 2 THEN event_code END)`, so that an empty string is concatenated when the `event_code` in the expression is NULL.

But otherwise - with your input (which you should take out of the query when you really use it), it could look like this:

```
WITH
-- your input, don't use in real query ...
tb1(Entry_Date,Cso_Item_Key,Fail_Code) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '8/1/2018 4:28','BLXB796201','CSL120'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '8/1/2018 4:40','BLXB799101','CLL250'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '8/1/2018 4:55','BLXB803001','CMS130'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '8/1/2018 5:08','BLXB806201','CNE100'
)
,
tb2(Cso_Item_Key,Event_Code) AS (
          SELECT 'BLXB796201','GTS'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB796201','LC28'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB796201','SDR4'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB799101','GTS'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB799101','LC28'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB799101','SDR4'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB803001','GTS'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB803001','LC28'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB803001','SDR4'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB806201','GTS'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB806201','LC28'
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLXB806201','SDR4'
)
,
tb3(Fail_Code,Descr) AS (
          SELECT 'CSL120','Bad Part'
UNION ALL SELECT 'CLL250','Unit Scrapped'
UNION ALL SELECT 'CNE100','OS Reinstall'
UNION ALL SELECT 'CBN101','NTF'
)
-- real WITH clause starts here - and table "i" can contain more than 3 rows..
,
i(i) AS (
          SELECT  1
UNION ALL SELECT  2
UNION ALL SELECT  3
)
,
tb2_w_i AS (
SELECT
  *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cso_item_key ORDER BY event_code) AS i
FROM tb2
)
,
tb2_pivot AS (
SELECT
  cso_item_key
,      MAX(CASE i.i WHEN 1 THEN event_code END)
||','||MAX(CASE i.i WHEN 2 THEN event_code END)
||','||MAX(CASE i.i WHEN 3 THEN event_code END)
  AS event_codes
FROM tb2_w_i JOIN i USING(i)
GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT
  entry_date
, tb1.cso_item_key
, tb1.fail_code
, descr
, event_codes
FROM tb1
JOIN tb2_pivot USING(cso_item_key)
LEFT JOIN tb3 USING(fail_code)
;
```

The result (my NULLSTRING is the dash..)

```
entry_date         |cso_item_key|fail_code|descr        |event_codes
2018-08-01 04:28:00|BLXB796201  |CSL120   |Bad Part     |GTS,LC28,SDR4
2018-08-01 04:40:00|BLXB799101  |CLL250   |Unit Scrapped|GTS,LC28,SDR4
2018-08-01 04:55:00|BLXB803001  |CMS130   |-            |GTS,LC28,SDR4
2018-08-01 05:08:00|BLXB806201  |CNE100   |OS Reinstall |GTS,LC28,SDR4
```